# What shall I do when I see spam (in one of the review queues)?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, flagging, review-queues

**In a few occasions if you use the review queues, you will find a post that is spam.**
The definition of spam according to StackExchange (and the internet in general; [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/260760)) is:

> What makes something spam and when should I flag it?
>   A post should be marked as spam **ONLY** when it contains an [unsolicited advertisement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29).
>
> It should **NOT** be marked as spam when:
>
> - The answer contains no useful information, such as an answer that says "I don't care about your problem". Flag an answer as 'not an answer' instead; if you find a weird non-question, then flag it 'for moderator attention' with a custom explanation.
> - It contains only gibberish, such as "fsdguejgkfdlk". Flag 'for moderator attention' with a custom explanation if it requires more detail. These flags are trivially handled by moderators and using spam/offensive for it poisons the data for anti-trolling and automated spam detection.

To give you a practical, recent example, that has been cleaned:

> We are manufacturer of [PyBOP](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/) *(← original link removed)* in China. If any needs, please do not hesitate to contact us. Thank you.

**What shall I do when I see a post like this?**

---

> > *Editorial note: This post shall be included in our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), so if you think something is missing, please edit it in, or if that is not possible, leave a comment below. It will be taken care of.*

Comment: I would add that I share the same sentiments towards Late Answers from new users that ask a question. **Don't guide people who are only going to be a burden on the moderation group™ of the community.**

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. I don't quite understand how that relates to spam?

Comment: Mart my first sentence does imply it's not related to spam. If it was, it would've been in the answer and not as a comment.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. OK - gotcha.

Answer (score 5):

### I found spam somewhere on the site, what happens now?

Whenever you see spam, you should **flag** it as "*spam*".
Click on the **flag** button below the post, it should look something like this:

Flag button on a question:
[image: Flag button on a question.]

Flag button on an answer:
[image: Flag button on an answer]

The flagging dialogue will pop up and you need to choose **spam**. It should look something like this:

[image: Screenshot of dialogue.]

### I found spam in the First Posts or Late Answers review queue

Do the same as above. **Just** flag it as spam. Don't edit and even commenting is unnecessary. If it really is spam it should be removed quickly. (Click 'I am done' and it will still count as a review.)

### I found spam in the Low quality review queue

**Open** the post in a new window since you cannot flag from within this queue and follow the steps above. It is somewhat important that the post receives the spam flags, so that eventually it will get auto deleted. *Additionally*, you can vote to delete/ recommend to delete it in this queue to dismiss it. You can also skip it, so that it stays in the queue longer and more people get to see it, so that it gets deleted quicker.

**The most important part is, that you flag it as "*spam*" in any case.**

### Someone is suggesting a spam edits and I’m supposed to review it

Note that it's not uncommon for spammers to attack by trying to edit existing posts. Please be careful when reviewing suggested edits, and **reject** as '*spam or vandalism*' when you see fit.